# what information about user can a telegram bot access?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm new to telegram bots, 
I want to know when we add a telegram bot to a group, can it access to any information about group members??
and I know about privacy mode, whether it is on or off , can bot access to any information about the user who sent a message that the bot can read??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A bot has access to:

- The user's unique identifier (user id)
- The user's first name
- The user's last name (if the user has specified his last name in the settings)
- The user's username (if the user has configured a username)

The bot can only extract this info from a Message (i.e. it cannot *query* the group member's names).

If privacy mode is *disabled*, the bot can read *all messages sent in a group*. If it is *enabled*, a bot is *only receives messages aimed directly at the bot* (e.g. using a command or a reply to a message from the bot).
A user is able to check whether a bot has Privacy mode enabled/disabled in the list of group members.

Sidenote: take care when adding bots to a group that have privacy mode disabled, since they might be maliciously storing messages.

Sources:

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user
- https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#privacy-mode

Comment: But using the *group_ID* can i obtain information about the members list if bot is added to it?

Comment: It's quite the opposite about privacy mode: enabled means that bot **will not receive** all messages in the group, only commands. And you actually can check if this mode is enabled: look at bot in the list of group participants.

Comment: @v1sc3rr4k no, you can not obtain the list of group participants by groupID.

Comment: Is it able to check online status?

Comment: You can know bot privacy settings listing group members.