# General question(s) regarding privacy on telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

some of my questions are already answered by [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010100/what-information-about-user-can-a-telegram-bot-access), but could someone please help me with two real "real basic" things? I utilize a telegram bot to receive messages from my smarthome-system. My bot is already up and running and I can receive messages that have been sent via the HTTP(s) API.

- Why do I only receive messages on the mobile phone I've created the bot with (don't get me wrong - that's exactly the way I want it to be)?
- How can I ensure that no one else may read the messages that have been sent to the bot (e.g. if someone got the bot's name)?

Many thanks in advance and BR,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike channels whose messages can be viewed by anyone, bots send messages to each user individually. When you `start` a Telegram bot, the back-end program behind it, receives your unique identifier. From then on, the bot sends your messages only to you. No one else receives them, because their unique identifiers are different.